# how to Secure war inside tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat, war

I am deploying my web application as an war in tomcat. I don't want my war and extracted folder inside tomcat webapps to be exposed to others. Since it can be easily decompiled.

Kindly provide solution for this issue.

Comment: Define "others". What is your threat here? If you don't control the computer, you don't control the computer.

Comment: It's a server machine and others can also access the same for their use.

Comment: I think this answer will helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641771/how-to-secure-the-war-file-deployed-in-tomcat-server/37226652#37226652